# My query keeps allowing me to register an existing account

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to make a master account that adds students , and i want to show that a certain account is existing through Email or Unique USN(university student number)

```
<?php 
require 'config.php';

if (isset ($_POST['fname']) && (isset($_POST['mname']) && (isset($_POST['lname']) && (isset($_POST['email']) && (isset($_POST['usn']) && (isset($_POST['schedule'])))))))
{
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $mname = $_POST['mname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $usn = $_POST['usn'];
    $schedule = $_POST['schedule'];

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO students(fname, mname, lname, email, usn, schedule) VALUES (:fname, :mname, :lname, :email, :usn, :schedule))'; 

    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
```

executing variable/array

```
    if ($statement->execute([':fname' => $fname, ':mname' => $mname, ':lname' => $lname, ':email' => $email, ':usn' => $usn, ':schedule' => $schedule])) 
    {

        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'> alert('New Student Record Inserted Successfully'); </script>";
    }
```

tried to show error that a student with the same usn exists

```
        $check = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students WHERE 'usn' = :usn");
        $check->bindValue(':usn', $_POST['usn']);
        $check->execute();

    if($check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) > 0)
    {
    echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'> alert('User already exist.'); </script>";


    }
```

tried to show that a student with the same email exists

```
        $check2 = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students WHERE 'email' = :email");
        $check2->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $check2->execute();

    if($check2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) > 0)
    {
    echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'> alert('Email already exist.'); </script>";
    }

    if (empty ($_POST['fname']) or (empty($_POST['lname']) or (empty($_POST['email']) or (empty($_POST['usn']) or (empty($_POST['schedule']))))))

    {

        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'> alert('There are some field/s that must be filled.'); </script>";
    }


    }
?>
```

I tried doing this but it activates the error handlers instantly

Comment: Most of your queries failed. Why? Because of the quotes around the column names and you didn't check for the real errors

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you've quoted the column identifiers in your queries (`'usn' = :usn"` and `'email' = :email"`.) That's going to compare the bound values to the literal strings 'usn' and 'email'. So don't do that.

`if($check2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) > 0)` is also a problem.

If your query runs successfully, `$check2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` is going to be an array with one value, which does evaluate to > 0, regardless of the value in it. (PHP casts the array to int for comparison with 0, which is [undefined behavior](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting.from-other), but in this case apparently returns > 0.)

You need to [get the first column](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) from the result instead, and then refer to that in your if condition.

```
if ($check2->fetchColumn() > 0) ...
```

Also, regardless of any of this, if you have certain columns that should remain unique in your table, add unique indexes to them so they won't accept duplicate values even if your application doesn't catch them properly.

Comment: you missed all columns wrapped in single quotes

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner ah, sure did. It's funny, that would make the count return 0 every time, but then the way they were checking the result would make it look like >0 anyway.

Comment: Probably because they haven't exceptions set in their DSN.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Well, it is still a valid query, it just isn't doing what they want it to. i.e. `'email' = :email"` is still a valid expression, just one that will most likely never be true.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner added an explanation of that to the answer, and thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: thank you guys for point out my mistakes , i would try and fix this :)